# input() function receives the entry literally instead of making a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Comma Code
Say you have a list value like this:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
```

> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a
>   string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with and
>   inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam
>   list to the function would return 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'.
>   But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to
>   it.

I recently got help from a friend in helping me make this code.

```
list = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4']
def ryansthing(list):
    string = ''
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if not i > len(list) - 2:
            string += list[i] + ', '
        else:
            string += 'and ' + list[i] + '.'
    print(string)

ryansthing(list)
```

and it works (prints out thing1, thing2, thing3 and thing4.), but whenever I changed the code to:

```
list = input() <----- I changed this to input function instead of setting the variable manually.
def ryansthing(list):
    string = ''
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if not i > len(list) - 2:
            string += list[i] + ', '
        else:
            string += 'and ' + list[i] + '.'
    print(string)

ryansthing(list)
```

It'll separate each single character with a comma like:

```
[, ', t, h, i, n, g, 1, ', ,,  , ', t, h, i, n, g, 2, ', ,,  , 
', t, h, i, n, g, 3, ', ,,  , ', t, h, i, n, g, 4, ', and ]
```

When it asks me for input I just type in the same list like this: ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4'

Comment: If you need a one element list, you will need to do: `[input()]`.

Comment: you need to split the input to a list before processing it, like `a = input("Enter items delimited by comma\n").split(','); ", ".join(a[:-1]) + " and " + a[-1]`

Comment: @wiesion this is sliiiiightly wrong. The requirement states there should be a comma between the init of the list and the "and", where your code omits that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu']

def printTogether(aList):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(aList)):
        if i == 0:
            result = result + aList[i]
        elif i == (len(aList)-1):
            result = result + " and " + aList[i]
        else:
            result = result + ", " + aList[i]
    print(result)

printTogether(spam)
```

The task description is kinda misleading, but from the example they have provided, this is what I think they want

Comment: You've re-written the part of OP's program that was already working, and failed to address the part that wasn't.

Comment: `for i in range(len(some_list)): ... some_list[i]` is a code smell. Prefer `for i, el in enumerate(some_list): ... el`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to specify the way user puts the input data. If you want the input to be words separated by a space in a single line you can use the following code:

```
spam = input().split()
```

elif you want the Enter key pressed after each entry word, you can use the following code:

```
spam=[]
while l != '':
l = input().rstrip()
spam.append(l)
```

else: you can create your own way

Comment: `input().split().rstrip()` will fail with an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in that does this for you! It's called `str.join`, and you call it on the list to be joined.

```
>>> some_list = ["foo", "bar", "spam", "eggs"]
>>> ", ".join(some_list)
foo, bar, spam, eggs
```

However this doesn't take into account the "and" requirement. That should be fairly simple to handle just by re-writing the last item of the list.

```
>>> some_list = ["foo", "bar", "spam", "eggs"]
>>> some_list[-1] = "and " + some_list[-1]
>>> ", ".join(some_list)
foo, bar, spam, and eggs
```

Write it as a function with:

```
def line_them_up(lst):
    new_lst = lst[:]  # copy the list so we don't change the original
    new_lst[-1] = "and " + new_list[-1]
    return ", ".join(new_lst)
```

and get input with `input` and `split`. You can even map `strip` over the resulting list if you like, though it shouldn't be necessary.

```
user_list = map(str.strip, input("Enter a space-separated list: ").split())
```